# MongoDB IMongoCollection.AsQueryable().GroupBy: project list of matching documents per group instead of field using $$ROOT

Tags: mongodb, linq

is there a way to get back a list of the grouped documents using the LINQ syntax?

I would like to do something like the following:

```
collection.AsQueryable().GroupBy(c => c.Name, (k, s) => new { Name = k, Count = s.Count(), Documents = s });
```

Name and Count are working properly, but I can't find a way to project back the original documents. Using the old 2.x MongoDB .NET driver I used to do something like:

`new BsonDocument("$push", "$$ROOT")`
and add that with a corresponding field to the $group stage.

The accumulator documentation lists a translation from "select" to "$push":

http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.9/reference/driver/expressions/#accumulators

But using this I am only able to push a single field, where I want to push the full document.

Thanks in advance,
Ly